# Include Javascript as Plain (No file inclusion)

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, include

Is there a way to append Javascript to the body in the script tag without using a file? 
Normally you would do it with

```
wp_enqueue_script('name', 'path/to/js/file');
```

Is there a way to include js in the script tag directly?
Like:

```
<script>My awesome code </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can directly insert what you want in the header or the footer using the action [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) or `wp_footer`

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_script');

function custom_script(){
      ?>
      <script>My awesome code </script>
      <?php

}
```

You only have to put this in functions.php of your child theme

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the wp_add_inline_script() function in WordPress to add JavaScript code directly to the body of your web page without using an external file.

Here's an example of how you can use `wp_add_inline_script()` function to add JavaScript code to the body of your WordPress site:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_js' );
function my_custom_js() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'path/to/js/file', array(), '1.0', true );
   wp_add_inline_script( 'my-js', 'console.log("My awesome code");' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [Hello Dolly plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/) that comes with WordPress;

```
// File: wp-content/plugins/hello.php
// We need some CSS to position the paragraph
function dolly_css() {
    // This makes sure that the positioning is also good for right-to-left languages
    $x = is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right';

    echo "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #dolly {
                float: $x;
                padding-$x: 15px;
                padding-top: 5px;       
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 11px;
            }
        </style>
    ";
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'dolly_css' );
```

Like @benoti mentioned use `wp_head` hook in you don't need the admin side:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'function_callback' );
```

BTW, this plugins appends styles and the same works for scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your functions.php or snippet or plugin:

```
add_action('wp_head', function (){
?>
<script>PASTE GLOBAL JS CODE HERE</script>
<style>PASTE GLOBAL STYLES HERE</style>
<?php
});
```

Comment: This hook only fires on the login page.

Comment: Thanks! Solved with wp_head and anonymous function ;)